# Display one item from array in AngularJS without using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have JSON array like:

```
var data = [
{
  "name": "Jim",
  "age" : 25
},
{
  "name": "Jerry",
  "age": 27
}
];
```

in HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="val in data | filter:{age: age}:true">{{val.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

The above code is working fine as i want the output, but i don't want to use `ng-repeat` where it creates loop and then i filter.

is there any another way where i can directly select the DATA from array where `age = age` ??

Comment: You would still need to go through the array and find the matching ages, so the answer is no. If you really want to get users from age then you have to think about an alternative data structure.

Comment: Filters can be used anywere in angular expressions (there is nothing `ngRepeat`-specific about them). But it is not clear what exactly you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @link in comments, there is no way to pluck the object with the required age from the array without looping through it. However, you're right in thinking that using `ng-repeat` here is not appropriate if you only want to display a single object from the array, so ideally the required object should be stored in your controller.

One approach would be to use `$filter` in your controller instead:

```
$scope.obj_with_correct_age = $filter("filter")(data, {age: age});

<li>{{ obj_with_correct_age.name }}</li>
```

Answer (score 6):

Filters can be used in any angular expression (there is nothing `ngRepeat`-specific about them).
(They can be even used in JavaScript.)

E.g. the following expression displays the data associated with the first user (`limitTo:1`) that has an age of 25 (`filter:{age: 25}`), formatted as JSON (`json`):

```
{{data | filter:{age: 25}:true | limitTo:1 | json}}
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Amk4Q/)**.

Comment: What if I only want the name from the data received?

Comment: @shyamalparikh: You can use an expression like: `{{ (data | filter:{age: 25}:true | limitTo:1)[0].name }}`

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread but for completeness.

This works:

```
{{data.Systems[data.Detail.SystemId].System}}
```

This way, you don't need to filter the `data`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse single value of name. like {"name":"value"}.
so after $http post, i am assuming that your response in var data= response.

Now find, like **console.log(data[0].name);**
Here, result will be **Jim**